# SQL SERVER Contagem de itens de um Campo Calculado

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde, estou com dificuldades para realizar uma contagem de itens em SQL SERVER, 
Preciso realizar a contagem de uma coluna que EU MESMO CRIEI, onde existe uma regra, e está ocorrendo vários erros nos meus testes, erros no GroupBy entre outros,

Preciso realizar a contagem da coluna TIPO, somente dos itens que forem classificados em: *"DADOS"*

```
SELECT 
 [CAM_PF] As CAM
 ,[CAM_DT_REGISTRO] as DT_REGISTRO  
  ,[CAM_DT_BD]
  --Esta coluna deve ser contada, preciso saber quantos iten "DADOS" e quantos "HISTORICO" tem na relação que ele traz
     ,case when 
        ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],1)over (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] order by [CAM_CD] asc)) OR
        ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],2)over (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] order by [CAM_CD] asc)) OR
        ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],3)over (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] order by [CAM_CD] asc))                                    
        then 'Historico' else 'Dados' 
    end as Tipo
    FROM [KLABIN_SGL].[dbo].[TB_CAMINHAO]
    Where  [CAM_DT_REGISTRO] between GETDATE()-1 and GETDATE()
    and DATEPART(Hour, [CAM_DT_REGISTRO]) <= DATENAME(HOUR,SYSDATETIME())-1
    Order By [CAM_PF], [CAM_CD];
```

Eu preciso que Essa contagem seja feita pelo campo *[CAM_PF]*

Como mencionei, Quando monto as queryes, não consigo aplicar a regra abaixo:

```
 ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],1)over (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] order by [CAM_CD] asc))
```

ou tenho erro no GroupBy

Alguém pode me ajuda a realizar esta contagem / soma?

o Resultado deveria trazer 03 colunas sendo:[CAM_PF], [CAM_DT_REGISTRO], CONTAGEM

CAM

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou assim?

```
SELECT 
 [CAM_PF] As CAM
 ,[CAM_DT_REGISTRO] as DT_REGISTRO  
  ,[CAM_DT_BD]
  --Esta coluna deve ser contada, preciso saber quantos iten "DADOS" e quantos "HISTORICO" tem na relação que ele traz
     ,case when 
        ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],1)over (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] order by [CAM_PF], [CAM_CD] asc)) OR
        ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],2)over (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] order by [CAM_PF], [CAM_CD] asc)) OR
        ([CAM_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([CAM_DT_REGISTRO],3)over (PARTITION BY [CAM_PF] order by [CAM_PF], [CAM_CD] asc))                                    
        then 'Historico' else 'Dados' 
    end as Tipo
    FROM [KLABIN_SGL].[dbo].[TB_CAMINHAO]
    Where  [CAM_DT_REGISTRO] between GETDATE()-1 and GETDATE()
    and DATEPART(Hour, [CAM_DT_REGISTRO]) <= DATENAME(HOUR,SYSDATETIME())-1
    Order By [CAM_PF], [CAM_CD];
```

Comment: Olá, tudo bem?

Não consegui ver seu exemplo, pode reenviar? @FabianoLothor